# How to make parallel custom layers train fast?

Tags: tensorflow, parallel-processing

I have created a custom layer in tensorflow. I want to use many custom layers that I created in parallel. Though I am able to successfully create parallel custom layers and train them, it is extremely slow. Here is sample code of creating custom parallel layers.

```
class parallelProjective(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self,num_filters):
        super(parallelProjective, self).__init__()
        self.num_filters = num_filters
        self.all_layers = [Custom_Layer(sampling_size) for i in range(self.num_filters)]
    def call(self, inputs):
        x_list = [self.all_layers[f](inputs) for f in range(self.num_filters)]
        y = Concatenate()(x_list)
        return y
```

**How can I speed up the process of training with parallel custom layers?**

Comment: I have the same question. I think that using a for loop in the 'call' function is slowing your layer. Did you found a solution?